Computing a distance in general relativity
What is the distance of me (standing on Earth's surface) to the center of the Earth, according to General Relativity? I am looking for a concrete value.
This question is inspired by https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R3LjJeeae68&list=LL&index=10&t=836s about gravity being not a force. It talks about the fact that standing on the Earth's surface means accelerating upwards according to GR.
But if so, my distance to the Earth's center is increasing in time.
(You can invoke any suitable advanced math in your answer.)

Does this answer your question? How can you accelerate without moving?
